How to use raster tiles in the EPSG:27700 coordinate projection (swift)
I am trying to use the OS Leisure_27700 Map as a custom tile provider in Swift using MapKit (and some code written by ChatGPT). I successfully got the OSMap working in JS using Leaflet (which makes use of proj4 to convert coordinate projection). The CRS for that is as follows:
const crs = new L.Proj.CRS('EPSG:27700', '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489 +units=m +no_defs', {
    resolutions: [896.0, 448.0, 224.0, 112.0, 56.0, 28.0, 14.0, 7.0, 3.5, 1.75],
    origin: [-238375.0, 1376256.0]
});

(there is both a WMTS and XYZ raster tile URL available - examples here)
In Swift, I have successfully got OSM maps working, only because they use the same coordinate projection as MapKit - OSMaps do not work due to being EPSG:27700...
My question is, how do I convert the {x}, {y}, {z} that is passed into the tile provider URL in Swift to be in the correct coordinate projection for the Leisure_27700 map? (I assume they may be some maths to convert between them, however I cannot seem to find or figure out what it is)
edit: title
